# Make Knockout.JS subscribale globally available

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET application and i am using Knockout JS for some minimal Tasks in my application. However i have some EditorTemplates that are calculating values to display. I want access to this values from some other EditorTemplates. I thought i might use the native pub/sub functionality with Knockout, meaning i would write in one EditorTemplate the notification code, like so:

```
new ko.subscribable().notifySubscribers(this.calculatedValue, "customTopic");
```

and then receive this value when it changes in my other EditorTemplate

```
new ko.subscribable().subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert(newValue);            
    }, this, "customTopic");
```

Of course, this code wont work, as i am creating a `new ko.subscribable()` everytime.

How can i create a single `ko.subscribable` that is available in all my Views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you need to define a new instance of `subscribable` variable globally.
- Inside other sub view models `subscribe` to subscribable variable that you defined.
- Notify any subscribers by using `notifySubscribers` whenever any updates happens.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/149/

**View:**

```
 <div id="one">
    <h1>MainVM:</h1>
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput:Name">
    <hr>
  </div>

  //-------------------------------------------------
  <div id="two">
    <h1>SecondVM:</h1>
    <div data-bind="text:NameSecondVM"> </div>
  </div>
```

**Model:**

```
 var shouterValueOfName = new ko.subscribable();

<script type="text/javascript">
  var MainViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
     self.Name = ko.observable();
     self.Name.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        newValue = newValue ? newValue + " Sent from MainVM" : "" ;
        shouterValueOfName.notifySubscribers(newValue, "secondVMTakeThis");
    }, self);
  }        
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var SecondViewModel = function(){
     var self = this;
     self.SecondVM = ko.observable();
     self.NameSecondVM = ko.observable();
     shouterValueOfName.subscribe(function (newValue) {
       self.NameSecondVM(newValue);
     }, this, "secondVMTakeThis");
  }
</script>
var viewModelA = new MainViewModel();
var viewModelB = new SecondViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModelA, document.getElementById("one"));
ko.applyBindings(viewModelB, document.getElementById("two"));
```

Comment: This only works if it is written in one <script/> block in a single View. I am using multiple Views (multiple EditorTemplates) with each having a <script/> block at the end of it, doing different things. Sorry if i sound like a newb (i am!) but where and how would i declare this global shouter? I found the tutorial on the pub/sub topic, but every example i have seen is based around having multiple viewmodels inside a single View.

Comment: Look at the updated answer. It does not have to be inside a single VM. As long as your different scripts have been loaded to the page you can use this. Remember the `global shouter` is responsible for communicating between your VMs. You can use `var` in global scope (outside of all functions) to declare a global variable and it is also a property of the global object, which we access as `window` on browsers